# document.querySelectorAll does not detect the data of a multiple select

Tags: javascript, dom

i have this index:

```
<select id="lstIngredientes" name="lstIngredientes" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="Gambas" data-precio="2" data-base="S" class="base">Gambas</option>
                    <option value="Cerdo" data-precio="1.75" data-base="S" class="base">Cerdo</option>
                    <option value="Pollo" data-precio="1.50" data-base="S" class="base">Pollo</option>
                    <option value="Ternera" data-precio="2" data-base="S" class="base">Ternera</option>
                    <option value="Almendras" data-precio="0.50" data-base="N">Almendras</option>
                    <option value="Nuez" data-precio="0.60" data-base="N">Nuez</option>
                    <option value="Pimiento" data-precio="0.40" data-base="N">Pimiento</option>
                    <option value="Bambu" data-precio="0.60" data-base="N">Bambú</option>
```

and i want add it a restriction like this:

```
if(!document.querySelectorAll('option[data-base="S"]') ==1)
    mensaje("You can only choose one base ingredient.");


if(!document.querySelectorAll("option[data-base='N']").value > 0)
    mensaje("At least 1 optional ingredient.");
```

but I skip the two messages whether the condition is met or not.
Any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: not sure how an HTML collection is supposed to equal one?

Comment: If they have to select one of each, why is it not two different select elements?? Very weird UI

Comment: @epascarello  It could be, but doesn't have to be,  the op is using a multiple select..  Not too weird..

Comment: @Keith Yes, but the requirement is one S and one or more N.... so it is a multiple select acting as single select and a multiple select so adds a layer of validation/complexity that is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll will return an HTMLCollection, you can use it's length property to count the number.

The pseudo-class selector :checked can be used to only select options you have selected.

eg.

```js
document.querySelector('form').
  addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const baseCount =
       document.querySelectorAll('[data-base="S"]:checked').length;
     if (baseCount !== 1) {
       alert("You can only choose one base ingredient.");
       return;
     }
     const optCount = 
       document.querySelectorAll('[data-base="N"]:checked').length;
     if (optCount < 1) {
       alert("At least 1 optional ingredient.");
       return;
     }
     alert('Everything is good!!');
  });
```

```css
select {
  height: 140px;
}

[data-base="S"] {
  background-color: #EEF;
}
```

```html
<form>
<select id="lstIngredientes" name="lstIngredientes" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<option
  value="Gambas"
  data-precio="2"
  data-base="S"
  class="base">Gambas</option>
<option 
  value="Cerdo"
  data-precio="1.75"
  data-base="S"
  class="base">Cerdo</option>
<option 
  value="Pollo"
  data-precio="1.50"
  data-base="S"
  class="base">Pollo</option>
<option 
  value="Ternera"
  data-precio="2"
  data-base="S"
  class="base">Ternera</option>
<option 
  value="Almendras"
  data-precio="0.50"
  data-base="N">Almendras</option>
<option 
  value="Nuez"
  data-precio="0.60"
  data-base="N">Nuez</option>
<option 
  value="Pimiento" 
  data-precio="0.40" 
  data-base="N">Pimiento</option>
<option 
  value="Bambu" 
  data-precio="0.60" 
  data-base="N">Bambú</option>                  
</select>
<br/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The checked hadn't crossed my mind. And I did not know that it was not necessary to put the "option" in the querySelector. Very Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get selected options, you would need to use :checked to get the selected options.

```
var sSelected = document.querySelectorAll('option[data-base="S"]:checked');
console.log(sSelected.length);
```

To get all the values, you would need to loop since it is a collection

```
var nSelected = document.querySelectorAll('option[data-base="N"]:checked');
console.log(nSelected.length);
nSelected.forEach(function (option) {
  console.log(option.value, option.dataset.precio);
});
```